# Why is does my property different depending on where it is called?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have a `NSMutableArray` that is loaded with objects my `viewDidLoad` method. Just to check, I placed `NSLog(@"%d", [self.myMutableArray count]);` at the end of the viewDidLoad method and got 6.

When I place the same `NSLog` on another method like `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I get the same number, 6.

Problem is when I call that same `NSLog` from an `IBAction` method, I get 0. Why?

Also, what I'm really trying to do is **access this property from another class** but I get that it is empty:

```
HabitsTableViewController *habitsViewController = [[HabitsTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HabitsTableViewController" bundle:nil];
NSLog(@"%d",[habitsViewController.habits count]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're creating a new instance of `HabitsTableViewController`.  You need to maintain a pointer to the controller you want to affect.

One way to keep a pointer to another class, you declare it as a property.  Use strong if you need it retained in this class, or weak if it should be retained by another class.

In your .h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) HabitsTableViewController * pointerToHabitsTableViewController;
```

Then, in your .m when you call HabitsTableViewController assign it to the pointer instead:

```
_pointerToHabitsTableViewController = ...;
```

Then, change this:

```
HabitsTableViewController *habitsViewController = [[HabitsTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HabitsTableViewController" bundle:nil];
NSLog(@"%d",[habitsViewController.habits count]);
```

To This:

```
NSLog(@"%d",[_pointerToHabitsTableViewController.habits count]);
```

Comment: I understand that in calling it from another class but why is it 0 when calling it as `self.myMutableArray` in an `IBAction` method? Also, how would I keep the pointer to the controller in another class?

Comment: If you understand that's from another class, how is supposed that trying it with a new instance will work? Anyway, check out any method where you modify this array, because there's no chance that an IBAction method should return an empty array.

Comment: I added a clarification on pointers, but the problem is that you're creating a new version.  Imagine you have a type of car, let's say a Jeep.  You put a bunch of stuff in your red jeep.  Then later, you get a brand new Jeep from the dealership and wonder why all your stuff isn't in it.  You need directions to your original red jeep's location to find the stuff that's supposed to be in it.  The pointer points to the original object's location in memory.

Comment: I miswrote that. It was two seperate questions. I understand that a new instance will show an empty array. What I don't understand is how the `IBAction` method is showing an empty array. If that's just not possible as @EridBardhaj says, I will just dive deeper in to the code in order to see what might be modifying the array.

Comment: If you understand that a new instance would have an empty array, why would you expect a new instance to not be an empty array when it's in an IBAction?  I think you're misunderstanding something.  Can you tell me why you expect IBAction to retain a pointer?

Comment: Because the IBAction is inside the original class with the array. The new instance, where I'm trying to access the array, is in another class.

Comment: If you're trying to access the array within the class, use `self`.  Don't create a new object of the same class as self.

Comment: Wherever you store an object in memory, that's the only place it will ever be(without copying).  You need to access that specific instance to get its values.  There's no way for a new instance to get values from an unrelated instance in any way without somehow providing that data's location in memory.  Via a pointer

Comment: ahh got it! Sorry for my dumb questions. I appreciate your patience.

Comment: No problem, everybody's gotta start somewhere! :)

Answer (score 0):

You HabitsTableViewController variable is release, to prevent release must save an NSMutablearray if you plan to use multiple instances or in a variable HabitsTableViewController in you class.h